# how to read env variables within github action which is used in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, github, yaml, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to run some test cases on GitHub action when pull request is sent.
I have some env variables which are used in various files. I faced an issue to read env variables from only one file, which is docker-compose.yml.

how can I read that within GitHub action?

my `docker-compose.yml` and `action.yml` files are here:

https://gist.github.com/ashiqdev/21781af493f156aca32313b68aedbc74

Answer (score 0):

Lack of knowledge of GitHub actions blocks the exact answer for this question. Instead i have a suggestion for you.

What if you store your variables not in `docker-compose.yml` file, but to store references to actual env variables, that you would pass withing the file?

For example, you could store all env vars in `.env` file, and docker-compose will use it by default. [source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file)

Also, you could specify different env-files for your docker-compose services, [with this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option).

That will let you to use docker-compose variables the same way as you do with other env-files.